# Problema con manejador de eventos de react y ciclo de vida

Tags: reactjs

Estoy creando un nuevo proyecto con react js y tengo el siguiente problema: he creado con metodo llamada handlechange, que se ejecuta cada vez que se realiza un cambio en un input.
Pero haciendo la ejecucion de ejemplo a travez de la consola me doy cuenta que no funciona bien.  si en el input escribo JUAN, en la consola me aparece que mi nuevo estado no es JUAN sino JUA . Esto quiere decir que el programa tiene un cierto retraso. El ultimo cambio no lo ejecuta. no entiendo porque.

Porfa. ayudenme a solucionarlo.

La siguiente imagen es el resultado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora les dejare el codigo

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class Perfiles extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
         nombre:'nombre',año:'',mes:'',dia:'',lugar:'',ciudadresidencia:'',direccionresidencia:'',hijos:'',
         datos:[]
    };
    this.add= this.add.bind(this);
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    //this.fetchperfil=this.fetchperfil.bind(this);
}
handleChange(e){
    //const {name,value}=e.target;

    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value
    });

    console.log([e.target.name] + e.target.value);
    console.log(this.state);
}

.......mas codigo
```

luego en el form tengo

```
<form onSubmit={this.add}>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="nombre" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" value={this.state.nombre} />
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                     <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <p>Fecha de nacimiento</p>
                                             <input name="año" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Año" value={this.state.año} />
                                             <input name="mes" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Mes" value={this.state.mes} />
                                             <input name="dia" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Dia" value={this.state.dia} />

                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="lugar" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Lugar de nacimiento" value={this.state.lugar}  />
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="ciudadresidencia" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Ciudad de residencia" value={this.state.ciudadresidencia} />
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="direccionresidencia" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Dirección de residencia"value={this.state.direccionresidencia}/>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="hijos" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Número de hijos"value={this.state.hijos}/>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>

                                     <button className="btn light-blue darken-4"> Añadir Perfil de Colaborador</button>

                                 </form>
```

En verdad no entiendo porque no funciona a la perfeccion.. La consola no me muestra error. pero si se esta presentando el retraso. El estado no se esta modificando como es debido
dejare todo el codigo

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import { Mongoose } from 'mongoose';
//import { throws } from 'assert';

class Perfiles extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
         nombre:'nombre',año:'',mes:'',dia:'',lugar:'',ciudadresidencia:'',direccionresidencia:'',hijos:'',
         datos:[]
    };
    this.add= this.add.bind(this);
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    //this.fetchperfil=this.fetchperfil.bind(this);
}
add(e){
    fetch('/perfiles/', {
        method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("data");
       M.toast({html:'tarea guardada'});
       this.setState({nombre:'',año:'',mes:'',dia:'',lugar:'',ciudadresidencia:'',direccionresidencia:'',hijos:''});
       this.fetchperfil();

    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    e.preventDefault();
}


componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchperfil();  
}

fetchperfil(){
    fetch('/perfiles/')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>{this.setState({datos:data});
});

}

/*eliminar(e){
    fetch('/perfiles/'+e,{
        method:'DELETE',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res=res.json())
    .then(data=>{
        M.toast({html:'Perfil Eliminado'});
        this.fetchperfil();
    });

}*/
handleChange(e){
    //const {name,value}=e.target;

    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value
    });

    console.log([e.target.name] + e.target.value);
    console.log(this.state);
}

render(){
    return(<div>
        <nav className="light-blue darken-4">
             <div className="container">
                    <a className="brand-logo" href="/">Talento Humano application</a>
                </div>
             </nav>

             <div className="container">
                 <div className="row">
                     <div className="col s5">
                         <div className="card">
                             <div className="card-content">
                                 <form onSubmit={this.add}>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="nombre" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" value={this.state.nombre} />
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                     <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <p>Fecha de nacimiento</p>
                                             <input name="año" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Año" value={this.state.año} />
                                             <input name="mes" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Mes" value={this.state.mes} />
                                             <input name="dia" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Dia" value={this.state.dia} />

                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="lugar" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Lugar de nacimiento" value={this.state.lugar}  />
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="ciudadresidencia" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Ciudad de residencia" value={this.state.ciudadresidencia} />
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="direccionresidencia" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Dirección de residencia"value={this.state.direccionresidencia}/>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="row">
                                         <div className="input-field col-s12">
                                             <input name="hijos" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Número de hijos"value={this.state.hijos}/>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>

                                     <button className="btn light-blue darken-4"> Añadir Perfil de Colaborador</button>

                                 </form>

                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>

                     <div className="col s7">
                         <table>
                             <thead>
                                 <tr>
                                     <th>Nombre</th>
                                     <th>Ciudad</th>
                                 </tr>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Nombre</td>
                                     <td>Ciudad</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 {
                                     this.state.datos.map(PERFILES=>{
                                         return(
                                             <tr key={PERFILES._id}>
                                                 <td>{PERFILES.nombre}</td>
                                                 <td>{PERFILES.ciudadresidencia} </td>
                                             </tr>
                                         )
                                     })
                                    }
                             </tbody>
                         </table>
                     </div> 

                 </div>
             </div>
    </div>);
}
};

export default Perfiles;
```

Comment: Solamente cambia el `onChange` de los `input` por el evento `onKeyPress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que describes no es un error, sino el como funciona react.
Las actualizaciones de estado [se realizan de manera asíncrona](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), por lo que si llamas a `setState` e inmediatamente consultas `this.state`, ten por seguro que no van a salir reflejados tus cambios. La prueba clara de que si está funcionando es que logras ver en pantalla los cambios reflejados en tus inputs, los cuales por lo que veo, están controlados por tus states, como:

```
<input name="nombre" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" value={this.state.nombre} />
```

Te recomiendo revisar [El ciclo de vida del componente](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle), para que determines donde deberías realizar las acciones correspondientes a tu manejo de state.